# Display product category AFC field on Single product page shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display advanced custom fields from my Product categorie on the product page that it is in.

so lets say I am on Home > category1 > category2 > Product

Category 2 is always a brand so I made a custom field where the value is "YES" if the product is a brand an "NO" if it isn't a brand.

This displays the category AFC but not the last one so not category2 but category1 `code`

```
<?php
function get_current_product_category1(){

        global $post;

       $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

        $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag'  );

        foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {                    

            $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;              

            // $product_cat_name = $term->name;      
            
            $product_cat_name = get_field('merk_header_afbeelding', $term);
            

            break;

        }

       return $product_cat_name['url'];


}
add_shortcode ('categorie_acf2', 'get_current_product_category1');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I made a custom field that makes it a **category2** or **category1** and I filter on that so I only get back the **Category2** items.

```php
function get_current_product_category5() {
    global $post;

    $terms  = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );

    foreach ( $terms  as $term ) {
        $product_cat_id   = $term->term_id;

        $product_cat_name = get_field( 'is_is_deze_categorie_een_merk', $term );

        // check if product AFC is ja
        if ( $product_cat_name === 'ja' ) {
            $product_cat_name2 = get_field( 'merk_header_afbeelding', $term );
        }
    }

    return $product_cat_name2['url'];
}
add_shortcode( 'categorie_acf3', 'get_current_product_category5' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a break inside the for loop. Try without the break.

EDIT: Adding the code snippet to print the link to the category with "brand" custom field set to "Yes".

This will print only the first category with brand "Yes". If there are more of them, then you should concatenate all of them into one string.

```
function get_current_product_category5(){

    global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {

        $is_brand = get_field('is_brand', $term);
        if($is_brand == "Yes")
        {
            return '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '">'.$term->name.'</a>';
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode ('categorie_acf3', 'get_current_product_category5');
```

Comment: No doens't work On some It still shows Category1 instead of the last

(I think I need to filter it on my custom field that is true if it is category2 and false if it is Category1)

Comment: Yes, that code will loop all categories and display the last one if you don't have break or the first one with the break. So you want to check your custom field for every category you iterate and then break when the custom field is yes